# I need to run a batch file from USB which will run a second batch file on C:, then allow me to remove the USB media. How can I do this?

Tags: windows, usb, batch, batch-file

I currently have a script that copies a directory on USB to C:, then runs the following line to switch to a local batch file:

`call "cmd /c start c:\update\patcher.cmd"`

Once the script on C:\ starts running, I need to be able to remove the USB and do the same thing on the next computer. When I try to remove the flash drive it says that it's still in use until I close the command prompt that is running from C:. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: tried cmd /k to start a new instance of cmd rather than /c to reuse the current one?

Comment: I just tried that, it says the removable media is still in use.

Comment: what if you do `start cmd /c "start c:\update\patcher.cmd"` EDIT:did some testing, it definitely is /c not /k

Comment: Same behavior as before but with an extra command prompt opening up at the external directory

Comment: But I dunno. Anyway, just because the usb stick still has a handle on the file doesn't mean you can't actually eject the stick. All you need to ensure is that the files were all copied and that the USB stick is not doing anything anymore to prevent corruption of the files. If that is the case, you can just eject the stick.

Comment: the /k is wrong, must be /c.

Comment: Windows won't let me eject it, are you just saying to pull it if I know it isn't doing anything? The light on it is still blinking periodically. Once the spawned command window running from C: is closed it lets me eject it

Comment: That's indeed what I mean, but if the light is still blinking, that means something is being done on the USB stick. Are you sure that it is indeed running from the c: script, and not the USB stick script? What happens if you rC script simply has the word pause in it? does it blink too or stop?